# How to search specific word in all files while connecting with ftp server in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

Is there a way to find specific words or phrase in all files in a directory
while connecting with ftp server in VScode?

If I download the whole files in ftp server, then it is possible to search the words in all files
However, connecting with ftp server through VScode and, trying to find the words in all files,
it doesn't work. It does work only for specific php file which I chose.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to know what operating system you are on. You may try the command "grep". [Here is some documentation on the command.](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

I hope this helps, or someone else is able to help you quickly!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).